# POST Operation - Web API Request format

Tags: android, image, byte, httpclient

```
http://REST-SERVICE/Requests.svc/[ID]/media/
```

HTTP Method: POST

Request, Unknown format, The request body is a byte stream.

How would I go about posting an image to the server using this particular request in Android?

I've tried to convert the image to a byte array:

```
> byte[] imageByte = stream.toByteArray();
> 
> httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(imageByte));
> httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

This doesn't work and just returns a (400) Bad Request error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request should transfer images, you can use multipartEntity.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
FileBody f = new FileBody(new File(path), "image/jpeg");
entity.addPart("picture", f);

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Alright I'll give this a try and hopefully give an update if this works or not. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't end up working. I took me a bit to get the MultiparEntity jars added to get it working, but after it was added, I got the same error (Request Error). Also got a lot of depreciation warnings. Post method very similar to this web service (except this one is a PDF upload): [link](http://www.capconnect.co.uk/CAPConnect/Webservice/FileExport.svc/help/operations/EmailPDFFile)

Comment: Sorry for very late answer, but there was an issue with the test site that I was posting to. Your code worked fine when trying external sites. There was just something wrong with the particular web service that I was posting to.